# How can I check if connection to Sql Server is encrypted?

Tags: sql-server, encryption, connections

In SQL Server I can "Force Encryption" in protocols settings. If I leave that set to "No" any client can still require encryption.

Can I somehow see what connections to the database are using encryption?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From [TechNet sys.dm_exec_connections DMV](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396): the encrypt_option will display FALSE if the connection is not encrypted.

Here is an example TSQL statement that can be run by administrators (VIEW SERVER STATE is the required privilege):

```
SELECT session_id, connect_time, net_transport, encrypt_option, auth_scheme, client_net_address 
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
```

Comment: By default, this does not work for non-sysadmins.  Accessing the dm_exec_connections view requires VIEW SERVER STATE permission on the server, which is not granted by default.  Do you know of an alternative, which by default, all logins can access ?

Comment: why would a non 'VIEW SERVER STATE' user have any business checking whether connections are encrypted?

Comment: @MitchWheat The same reason you, a *'standard user'*, can see the  padlock icon up top in your browser right now - to know that their connection is encrypted. Users `must not` need administrator privileges to ensure encryption is being used. tldr: for security

Comment: If a standard user (I would say a client application) want a encrypted connection. It has to use/check the dedicated key (Encrypt=True) in the connexion string !

Answer (score 5):

There are various methods to check the connections :

1. You can use a third party tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) which lets you see what's happening on your network at a microscopic level and will help you in getting those encrypted connections.
2. You can also use the [Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=4865) to get those connection details.
3. And as mentioned by travis you can also look at `encrypt_option` column of the `sys.dm_exec_connections` DMV

In addition please read the article which will help you understand more on this [Encrypting connections in SQL Server 2005 & SQL Native Client with SS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2005/11/10/491563.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Please note that in **SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) the "View connection properties" does not show if the connection is Encrypted**. It only shown if the client (SSMS) has asked for the connection to be encrypted.

[image]

If you are using `Force Encryption = true` on the server configuration all connections will be encrypted, but SSMS will not indicate it.

You can validate the connection on the server with:

```
SELECT encrypt_option,* FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
```

`encrypt_option` will be `true` for encrypted connections

[image]

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to add any new information to the earlier accepted answer.

Comment: It add the very often reason for why people ask this question, "SSMS connection properties does not show if the connection is Encrypted"

Comment: @mustaccio StackExchange [is a combination of Reddit and Wikipedia](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/09/15/stack-overflow-launches/). As such, more relevant information is always welcome.

Comment: Thanks, this helped with some head scratching on my end.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check whether the connection in encrypted in the SSMS, when you connect to a server with encryption, you will see a lock icon next to the server name in the bottom panel:
[image: encrypted connection SSMS]

Without encryption, there is only server name without lock icon.